# County-Level Ethnic Shapefile: United States

Tags: qgis, shapefile, data, database, choropleth

My professor usually provides the shapefiles that we deal with in our analyses of the United States--population, votes, etc., but I'd like to know how I can get these myself. I'd like, in particular, a shapefile with ethnic data listing the percent with respect to total population. I'm new to this, so keep that in mind.

[image]

I'd like to make an overlay of these data with the data in the above county-level population map of the United States to make an interesting comparison with another overlay of the 2012 presidential election results.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out http://geocommons.com/ it's good source to get shapefiles, csv and geojson files.

More specifically you are looking something similar http://geocommons.com/overlays/178735

I hope it will help.

Comment: Hey, @FarhatAbbas, to which journalists to you provide such data? Has any of your work showed up in the press? I'd be interested in getting involved in such processes.

Comment: Hi @Trancot i really didn't get you. would be good to have one2one session on skype my id on skype is farhatabbasnaqvi :)

Answer (score 1):

[US Census Bureau](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html) may have what you are looking for. Just Google what specifically you are looking for and see what comes up.